# Bevel modifier with limit weight and edge weight creates bad topology vs bevel tool, why?

Tags: topology

The topology using the bevel tool behaves as expected, however, when using the bevel modifier with the limit method "weight" and "edge weight" applied it creates bad topology. Please take a look at the screenshots below.

[image]

https://imgur.com/m7GD4lV

Thank you for the help

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your file? I've tried with the same shape and it gives the same result with or without Bevel modifier: https://zupimages.net/up/23/39/oxtm.jpg

Comment: Sure thing, uploaded! Interesting. I don't believe this is normal, right? Or have I just never noticed. I swear it has always beveled appropriately before but perhaps I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing would happen if you chose to bevel the whole mesh manually.

If you bevel the horizontal edge loop manually, and bevel the vertical edge with the modifier, it won't create the problem, but that's normal: When you bevel with the modifier only, the horizontal bevel takes into account the topology that is virtually created by the vertical beveled edges. While if you manually bevel the horizontal edge loop, this manual bevel won't take into account the topology that is created by the bevel modifier on the other edges, as a modifier only creates a virtual topology.

If you don't want the topology you highlight, I guess you need to either mix bevel modifier and manual bevel, or bevel manually in 2 steps (vertical edges first, then horizontal edge loop, or vice versa).

Also don't forget to apply the scale if you want a bevel that is not stretched.